# Lua, Odd behavior with bitmap reading

Tags: image, image-processing, lua

In a bitmap reader I found and modified, the first few colors of some images are innacurate by a large amount, in other images it reads perfectly, in just now, the first 7 or so colors of an image that I must have it read are not accurate at all. I don't understand byte orders, so please help!

Heres my modified copy of the code:

```
---
-- (Evil Steve)Because I'm a kind and wonderful person: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/572784-lua-read-bitmap/
---

function error(err)
    -- Replace with your own error output method:
    print(err);
end

-- Helper function: Parse a 16-bit WORD from the binary string
function ReadWORD(str, offset)
    local loByte = str:byte(offset);
    local hiByte = str:byte(offset+1);
    return hiByte*256 + loByte;
end

-- Helper function: Parse a 32-bit DWORD from the binary string
function ReadDWORD(str, offset)
    local loWord = ReadWORD(str, offset);
    local hiWord = ReadWORD(str, offset+2);
    return hiWord*65536 + loWord;
end

-- Process a bitmap file in a string, and call DrawPoint for each pixel
function OpenBitmap(File, Stream)
    if Stream == nil then Stream = false end
    local bytecode = File:read("*a")

    -------------------------
    -- Parse BITMAPFILEHEADER
    -------------------------
    local offset = 1;
    local bfType = ReadWORD(bytecode, offset);
    if(bfType ~= 0x4D42) then
        error("Not a bitmap file (Invalid BMP magic value)");
        return;
    end
    local bfOffBits = ReadWORD(bytecode, offset+10);

    -------------------------
    -- Parse BITMAPINFOHEADER
    -------------------------
    offset = 15; -- BITMAPFILEHEADER is 14 bytes long
    local biWidth = ReadDWORD(bytecode, offset+4);
    local biHeight = ReadDWORD(bytecode, offset+8);
    local biBitCount = ReadWORD(bytecode, offset+14);
    local biCompression = ReadDWORD(bytecode, offset+16);

    if(biBitCount ~= 24) then
        error("Only 24-bit bitmaps supported (Is " .. biBitCount .. "bpp)");
        return;
    end

    if(biCompression ~= 0) then
        error("Only uncompressed bitmaps supported (Compression type is " .. biCompression .. ")");
        return;
    end

    ---------------------
    -- Parse bitmap image
    ---------------------
    local TmpImg = {}
    if Stream == false then
        for y = biHeight-1, 0, -1 do
            offset = bfOffBits + (biWidth*biBitCount/8)*y + 1;
            for x = 0, biWidth-1 do
                local b = bytecode:byte(offset);
                local g = bytecode:byte(offset+1);
                local r = bytecode:byte(offset+2);
                offset = offset + 3;

                TmpImg[#TmpImg+1] = {r,g,b}
            end
        end
    else
        for y = biHeight-1, 0, -1 do
            offset = bfOffBits + (biWidth*biBitCount/8)*y + 1;
            for x = 0, biWidth-1 do
                local b = bytecode:byte(offset);
                local g = bytecode:byte(offset+1);
                local r = bytecode:byte(offset+2);
                offset = offset + 3;

                TmpImg[#TmpImg+1] = r
                TmpImg[#TmpImg+1] = g
                TmpImg[#TmpImg+1] = b
            end
        end
    end

    return TmpImg, biWidth, biHeight
end

function OpenBmp(FileName, Stream)
    if Stream == nil then Stream = false end
    if FileName == nil then
        return false
    end

    local File = assert(io.open(FileName, 'rb'))
    local Data, Width, Height = OpenBitmap(File, Stream)

    File:close()
    return Data, Width, Height
end
```

I cannot give you the code I run with this, sadly, because it has too many dependencies to bother with, but its output is:

```
<254, 254, 254, 256>
<99, 254, 254, 256>
<49, 74, 91, 256>
```

When ran with the following bmp colors:

```
<90, 106, 113, 256>
<188, 194, 197, 256>
<254, 254, 254, 256>
```

I don't see any pattern, and the bmp reader seems to make sense, it prints no errors when reading, and I made sure to save the bmp as 24 bit as required. all help appreciated :-)

Comment: Yu Hao, I included a link to the source of this function, as I thought it might be usefull for people reviewing my post, to make comparisons and see what I changed, is this against stack overflow rules? I did not intend it to be 'spam'

Comment: Then I was wrong to call it "spam" in the edit, sorry about that. But still, you should add the link in the question with some explanations, not in the code comment after the sentence: *(Evil Steve)Because I'm a kind and wonderful person*. I still don't understand it now.

Comment: That was the permissions I was given the code under, and the username of the person who gave it to me, via a public post on a forum. I kept it there to give credit, since lua code is easily copyable, it could land in the hands of others, who might assume it was my original work(which it is not); as well as I don't want any legal problems, as it was posted without copy-write, I thought it wise to source it, as to not be interpreted as theft in the future.

Comment: In my opinion, "-- (Evil Steve)Because I'm a kind and wonderful person: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/572784-lua-read-bitmap/" is an odd way to give credit. If you want to credit the source, just say something like "Original code by Evil Steve from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/572784-lua-read-bitmap/)".

Comment: Sorry, a post by my brother while he was using my computer, I don't see it as a joke, and am quite serious about it, that it could seem somewhat comical, yes, but I included it as sourcing for where I got the script from, sorry for my brother's post, I didn't mean for there to be more argument over the first three commented lines of my code than the next hundred lines of real code, I just want my question answered, the posted code above is exactly what it looks like in my source file, I did not add the controversial comments 'just for'. I can accept correction, but leave the link in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example above, offset wasn't considering that row widths must always be a multiple of 4 bytes wide, with it padded if it was below the multiple of 4. You can resolve this by rounding up row width to the nearest multiple of 4, which explains why the function sometimes read images accurately, and other times not.

the behavior from the pixels in the beginning being false, but the rest later on being accurate was due to creeping, logically, the first would be accurate, with the last inaccurate, but the creeping went the opposite way due to bitmaps being read bottom-up and right-left.